# Weird Black Worm (Possibly Flatworm?)

Tags: species-identification, zoology

I was out walking one night (In Florida) when I spotted this creature sliding around in the grass. I believe it may be a New Guinea Flatworm, but not quite sure. Could anyone please provide a definite ID? Thank you!

[image: Flatworm?]
[image: Flatworm?]